# Add rows and columns in UITableView iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Is it possible to add rows and columns to an UITableview in iPhone as shown below?

Please help me, I'm new to iOS development.

[image]

Comment: i m not seen any links or images  bro

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=columns+and+rows+in+android+app&client=ubuntu&hs=Ftg&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN5uXh1qnMAhWEnJQKHTqNBSwQ_AUICCgC&biw=1615&bih=955#imgrc=hEitnf9Wwc8WTM%3A

Comment: Please find the link. It should look similar like that

Comment: @ragulml In iOS Development there is no any kind of readymade controller you can use. But you need to develop like wise grid need to create custom cell for `UITableView` controller.

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: is their any links( like tutorial ) tat u could suggest me to achieve it.

Comment: @RDC - I have not yet started, I'm new to ios

Comment: As a new SO member, I would suggest please go through this section [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you need to create the view with single space additional ,

Comment: Why not use UICollectionView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I found the answer. 

UIView *newView124=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(224, 90, 2, 48)];
    newView124.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    [cell addSubview:newView124];

    //Initialize Label
    NSLog(@"cell width: %f",cell.frame.size.width);
    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 90, 100, 50)];
    [lbl1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FontName" size:12.0]];
    [lbl1 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    lbl1.text = @"1";
    [cell addSubview:lbl1];

    UIView *newView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 90, 2, 48)];
    newView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    [cell addSubview:newView];

    UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(42, 90, 130, 50)];
    [lbl2 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FontName" size:12.0]];
    [lbl2 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    lbl2.text = @"Hospitsal";
    [cell addSubview:lbl2];

    UIView *newView1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(172, 90, 2, 48)];
    newView1.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    [cell addSubview:newView1];



    UILabel *lbl21 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(174, 90, 50, 50)];
    [lbl21 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FontName" size:12.0]];
    [lbl21 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    lbl21.text = @"Active";
    [cell addSubview:lbl21];

    UIView *newView12=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(224, 90, 2, 48)];
    newView12.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    [cell addSubview:newView12];


    UIButton *modeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 100, 30, 25)];


    UIImage *ddd=[UIImage imageNamed:@"pencil.png"];

    [modeButton setImage:ddd forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    ///[btnEdit addTarget:self action:@selector(imSelected) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell addSubview:modeButton];
   // [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:btnEdit];



    UIView *aView1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 135,self.view.frame.size.width, 2)];
    aView1.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    [cell addSubview:aView1];
```

Comment: add this line to release memory, created

Comment: for(UIView *eachView in [cell subviews])
        [eachView removeFromSuperview];

Comment: Before adding the main code add the code in the comment.